# implement https on nginx config file

Tags: docker, nginx, vue.js, single-page-application, digital-ocean

I have a single page application written with vuejs
and i want to deploy the application using digitalocean, nginx and docker

my question is,
what do i need to add to the config file/docker file
to make that the app will use https and not http?
(i'm going to use self signed certificates)

yes, i searched the question already, but nothing seems to work
with that template.

also, the backend for this app is nodejs with express
that will be on different container on the same digital ocean server

Im using the docker file template from vue docs:

dockerfile:

```
# build stage
FROM node:9.11.1-alpine as build-stage
WORKDIR /app
COPY package*.json ./
RUN npm install
COPY . .
RUN npm run build

# production stage
FROM nginx:1.13.12-alpine as production-stage
COPY --from=build-stage /app/dist /usr/share/nginx/html
EXPOSE 80
CMD ["nginx", "-g", "daemon off;"]
```

nginx.conf:

```
user  nginx;
worker_processes  1;

error_log  /var/log/nginx/error.log warn;
pid        /var/run/nginx.pid;


events {
    worker_connections  1024;
}


http {
    include       /etc/nginx/mime.types;
    default_type  application/octet-stream;

    log_format  main  '$remote_addr - $remote_user [$time_local] "$request" '
                      '$status $body_bytes_sent "$http_referer" '
                      '"$http_user_agent" "$http_x_forwarded_for"';

    access_log  /var/log/nginx/access.log  main;

    sendfile        on;
    #tcp_nopush     on;

    keepalive_timeout  65;

    #gzip  on;

    include /etc/nginx/conf.d/*.conf;
}
```

Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just copy SSL and conf during build time keep both in `configs/nginx/` in the root of your docker file

```
# build stage
FROM node:9.11.1-alpine as build-stage
WORKDIR /app
COPY package*.json ./
RUN npm install
COPY . .
RUN npm run build

COPY configs/nginx/conf.d/ /etc/nginx/conf.d/
COPY configs/nginx/nginx.conf /etc/nginx/nginx.conf
COPY configs/nginx/ssl/ /etc/nginx/ssl/
RUN rm -rf /etc/nginx/conf.d/default.conf
# production stage
FROM nginx:1.13.12-alpine as production-stage
COPY --from=build-stage /app/dist /usr/share/nginx/html
EXPOSE 80
CMD ["nginx", "-g", "daemon off;"]
```

your nginx.conf

```
#test comment4
user  nginx;
daemon off;
worker_processes  1;

error_log  /var/log/nginx/error.log warn;
pid        /var/run/nginx.pid;


events {
    worker_connections  1024;
}


http {
    include       /etc/nginx/mime.types;
    default_type  application/octet-stream;

    log_format  main  '$remote_addr - $remote_user [$time_local] "$request" '
                      '$status $body_bytes_sent "$http_referer" '
                      '"$http_user_agent" "$http_x_forwarded_for"';

    access_log  /var/log/nginx/access.log  main;

    sendfile        on;
    #tcp_nopush     on;

    keepalive_timeout  120;

    gzip  on;

    include /etc/nginx/conf.d/*.conf;
}
```

**/etc/nginx/conf.d/mydoamin.com**

```
server {
        listen          80;
        server_name     mydomain.com default_server;
        add_header 'Cache-Control' 'no-store, no-cache, must-revalidate, proxy-revalidate, max-age=0';
        expires off;
        return  301     https://$server_name$request_uri;
}
server {
        listen 443 ssl;
        server_name mydomain.com;
        client_max_body_size 32M;
        add_header Strict-Transport-Security "max-age=31536000; includeSubdomains";

        ssl_certificate      /etc/nginx/ssl/mydomain.bundle.crt;
        ssl_certificate_key  /etc/nginx/ssl/mydomain.com.key;

  root "/usr/share/nginx/html";
  index index.html index.htm index.php; #####fruther config####
  }
```

So update command will be

```
 docker run -it --add-host boomerb2b.com:192.168.1.23 -p 443:443 -p 80:80 --rm --name app nginx-ssl:latest
```

Also, add value at /etc/hosts if not resolving domain

```
vim /etc/hosts/ 
192.168.1.23 boomerb2b.com
```

Comment: Hi! thanks for the answer, 
i didnt as you said here but still doesnt work, the forwarding to 443 is working but the app not serve to the user, not in port 80 or port 443. the page is unreachable, on the logs i can see the request for port 80 but when it becomes a port 443 request. the page failed to load

Comment: please share exact template so i will try with your template. this should work

Comment: docker file
https://bitbucket.org/boomeryo/boomer3/src/master/client/Dockerfile
nginx stuff(including the certificates):
https://bitbucket.org/boomeryo/boomer3/src/master/client/nginx_config/

auto build on dockerhub: (tag name: latest)
https://hub.docker.com/r/omer2500/boomer3/builds/
the command for running the container:
docker run -p 80:80 --rm --name app omer2500/boomer3:latest

Comment: let me try with your template

Comment: Thank you,
the links i gave here are ok?

Comment: https://drive.google.com/file/d/1WGPqm7oMEKSQCHiYlE-4ar_mOoE328vU/view?usp=sharing

Comment: @omern i check and its work fine the only thing you need to add value /etc/hosts/
192.168.1.23   boomerb2b.com and update your run docker run command. run command get your system IP using ifconfig or ipconfig then docker run will be 
docker run -it --add-host boomerb2b.com:192.168.1.23 -p 443:443 -p 80:80 --rm --name app nginx-ssl:latest